# bash run sbt test returns error

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, playframework, sbt

I have a playframework application where I want to run tests with jenkins. I have the following script:

```
rm -rf /opt/processes/*
cp -R $WORKSPACE/ /opt/processes/
cd /opt/processes/
sbt testOnly controllers.ProcessesTemplatesControllerSpec
```

locally on my windows machine that works fine.

but on jenkins I got this error:

```
No sbt.version set in project/build.properties, base directory: /opt/processes
Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
Not a valid command: controllers
```

jenkins is running under ubuntu

what could be my issue?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sbt command line interprets space separated parameters as separate commands. Quote them to pass as a single command:

```
sbt 'testOnly controllers.ProcessesTemplatesControllerSpec'
```